# Date in calendar-CRM

Tags: crm

In crm, the calendar reflects today's date as 10 august (system date is 27 nov), despite it already being november 2015. Not for all users. what could be wrong?

Comment: Which CRM system? There is more than one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the users system time on their computer?
Or the formatting settings on the computer? YYYY/MM/DD vs MM/DD/YYYY etc

Answer (score 0):

Check the user's time zone in user's options.
If you want to set same time zone, time format an other stuff to more than one user each time you can use this useful tool:

https://ourcrmtool.codeplex.com/